# When I'm running my parse push application throws a NullPointerException storage == null in Parse.initialize(ctx, "***", "***")

Tags: java, android

I Follow the parse quick start guide for push in Parse and always throws a NullPointerException storage == null

My application class

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

public Application() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "****", "***");//Here throws the exception
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

}

And the stacktrace

```
08-14 00:19:47.866  31836-31836/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.easypass.app.cliente, PID: 31836
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.easypass.app.cliente.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4463)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1274)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5280)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.hasRequestedPermissions(ManifestInfo.java:392)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.hasAnyGcmSpecificDeclaration(ManifestInfo.java:454)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushType(ManifestInfo.java:201)
        at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.registerAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:86)
        at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:230)
        at com.easypass.app.cliente.Application.onCreate(Application.java:19)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4460)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777829/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-java-lang-nu)

Comment: Google "arraylist storage == null".

Comment: can you try `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` in your                      `Parse.initialize(this, "****", "***");`

Comment: I tried with getApplicationContext() instead of this and got  this.  java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10112 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. In manifest I added the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` before initializing `Parse` . Like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "****", "***");//Here throws the exception
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

Comment: I tried with the enableLocalDataStore method and got the same exception. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I've tried like you said and now got this:                                              Neither user 10112 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.                                         I have the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in the manifest

Comment: Sorry, I have the permission in the wrong place :) It's ok now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 7):

Need to place the following permissions in your manifest file before the  tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```